# Xubuntu installation from DVD fails on ASUS D700SA desktop: Initramfs unpacking failed

Tags: system-installation, uefi, asus

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Xubuntu) from a DVD on an ASUS model D700SA-XB501.  (That is a small-tower desktop computer, sold as a "business computer."  The machine came with Windows 10 preinstalled.  I have successfully installed Xubuntu using this same DVD on several other computers.

When I attempt the installation on the ASUS D700SA, the initial GRUB menu appears, I see on the screen:
"GNU GRUB version 2.04"
followed by various options.  If I select any of the installation or try-without-installing options after about a minute I get the xubuntu splash screen with the circling arc and then a text screen saying:
[     0.375250] Initramfs unpacking failed:  Decoding failed

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Looking at the BIOS (UEFI) screens I see that the system has
BIOS Version 300,  GOP Version: 9.0.1105
Intel core i5-10400 @ 2.90 GHz
Intel UHD Graphics 630

I have tried it with "secure boot" enabled and disabled.  Same response in both cases.

I would much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried disabling UEFI? You should likely report this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syslinux